# Node modules can't be used in Nativescript app

Tags: javascript, npm, plugins, nativescript, tns

I'm trying to use several plugins in my Nativescript app. Unfortunately the computed path where to find these installed Plugins is not valid and I can't find any hint where to change this information.

Is there any possibility to define the path where nativescript is supposed to find all the plugins?

Comment: What you mean by "computed path where to find these installed Plugins", the dependencies are always listed in `package.json` and installed at node_modules folder. Are you talking about installing private dependencies from your local machine?

Comment: Nativescript is telling me, that it can't find the plugins. This "computed path", mentioned in the error message, is different from something like ".../node_modules/... - and as you said, this is where the plugins are actually installed. So I assume that the path at which Nativescript is searching for the plugins is wrong and that I have to change it.

Comment: The setup works out of the box you don't have to do any specific changes, can you share a Github sample where the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply. I've opened a new repo and fortunately there it worked. I have trouble sharing an example repo because of sensitive data in the project. It seems to work now though. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Node modules must be installed in your nativescript project directory.